# Deserialize DateTime in Symfony

Tags: symfony, deserialization, symfony-3.3

Trying to use the serializer component in Symfony 3.3. I struggle with entities having 'DateTime' members.

My config.yml serializer init:

```
serializer:
    enable_annotations: true
```

Added this in service.yml:

```
datetime_method_normalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer
    public: false
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

The deserialized code looks like this:

```
$yml = [...]   // It was created by serializer->serialize()
$serializer = $this->get('serializer');
$myObject = $serializer->deserialize($yml, MyObject::class, "yaml");
```

The error is get is: `Expected argument of type "DateTime", "string" given` in in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php (line 204)

I think the DateTimeNormalizer::denormalize never gets called. Any idea how to bring it back to life?

Info: DateTimeNormalizer::__constructor() is called.

Answer (score 4):

As DateTime is a nested object, you should use PropertyInfo Component as described here —
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety

> The extraction of property information is performed by extractor
>   classes.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_info.html#extractors

There are 4 types of extractors:

- ReflectionExtractor
- PhpDocExtractor
- SerializerExtractor
- DoctrineExtractor

For example, using ReflectionExtractor you need to specify type hint for either params or return type. It also looks for constructor params (requires to be enabled explicitly)

```
class Item {

   protected $date;

   public function setDate(\DateTime $date) {...}
   public function getDate() : \DateTime {...}
}
```

Property Info is registered automatically when option set:

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml 
framework:
  property_info: ~
```

After that you need to override *serializer* service to use it, or define a custom one. And the last part — add DateTimeNormalizer, so DateTime can be processed by serializer.

```
app.normalizer.item_normalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer
    arguments:
      - null
      - null
      - null
      - '@property_info.reflection_extractor'
    tags: [ 'serializer.normalizer' ]

app.serializer.item:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer
    public: true
    arguments:
      - [
          '@serializer.normalizer.datetime',
          '@app.normalizer.item_normalizer',
        ]
      - [ '@serializer.encoder.json' ]
```

That's it.

Comment: This is the proper solution. However, you should not be required to override or otherwise mess with `Serializer` service itself. `PropertyInfo` component once it registers in Symfony Framework should automatically inject itself into `ObjectNormalizer`, as it did in my case.

Comment: Just installing the symfony/property-info component worked for me in a symfony 4.4 application

Answer (score 3):

This question break my brain recently, and I've two entities with dateTime property, the solution is custom denormalizer like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Serializer\Normalizer;

use MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity1;
use MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity2;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

/**
 * DateTime hook normalizer
 */
class DateTimeHookNormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
        if (isset($data['MyDateTime1']) && is_string($data['MyDateTime1']))
        {
            $data['MyDateTime1'] = new \DateTime($data['MyDateTime1']);
        }
        if (isset($data['MyDateTime2']) && is_string($data['MyDateTime2']))
        {
            $data['MyDateTime2'] = new \DateTime($data['MyDateTime2']);
        }
        And more ...

        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();//default normalizer

        return $normalizer->denormalize($data, $class, $format, $context);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
{
    return is_array($data) && ($type === MyEntity1::class || $type === MyEntity2::class);
}
```

And declare service like this :

```
# DateTime Hook Normalizer
Mybundle.normalizer.dateTimeHook:
    class: 'MybundleBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeHookNormalizer'
    public: false
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

It's ok for me, that work !

Comment: I use this workaround too, but it's weird that I don't need it on some projects..

Comment: Worked great, thank you. I just don't understand why you need to declare the service? I just have this in my testClass: `$dateTimeNormalizer = new DateTimeNormalizer();
        $normalizers = array($dateTimeNormalizer);`

Answer (score 0):

The only official way is seems to declare a `callback`:

```
$callback = function ($dateTime) {
return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime
    ? $dateTime->format(\DateTime::ISO8601)
    : '';
};

$normalizer->setCallbacks(array('createdAt' => $callback));
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances

Comment: Thanks. Using callbacks will be unpleasant because the names of DateTime properties will change while the software evolves. If it doesn't translate from string to DateTime, what is the purpose of `DateTimeNormalizer`?

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. The `AbstractNormalizer::setCallbacks` method _only_ applies normalizers, not denormalizers. Normalizers convert typed values into array values ready for encoding into serialised strings. The question is about the other direction: denormalising array values back into typed values, as part of the deserialisation process from an encoding to an object.